# Sound is not there and says it is deleted as per info beow

Tags: audio, windows-10

I have a Lenovo B50 Touch with Windows 10.  This is screenshot of events

> Driver Management concluded the process to install driver
>   hdxpcee4.inf_amd64_da34793fa5397387\hdxpcee4.inf for Device Instance
>   ID
>   HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_0235&SUBSYS_17AA3802&REV_1000\4&32AA8BE&0&0001
>   with the following status: 0x0.

This below is the event. I don't know what happened but two week ago when I tried to use audio this appears what shut it down ??

```
Device HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_0235&SUBSYS_17AA3802&REV_1000\4&32AA8BE&0&0001 was deleted.

Class Guid: {4D36E96C-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}
```

How do I reverse this and get it working again?

Comment: There is no screenshot. Take a screenshot & imbed a link. Also use the formatting tools to make your question more readable

Comment: @Earl In the past for a similiar problem with a drive, I simple went to the Device Manager, selected UNINSTALL of the device with the issue, etc. and then reboot the PC. When it boot back up, Windows reinstalled the drivers correctly and all was working -- this was for an AUDIO driver in particular and I had other PCs and Internet access otherwise to download manually and reinstall. If you decide to give that a shot and it works, I'll be happy to add as an answer something to consider perhaps at least. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

There is a "rollback driver" function in device manager

Open Device manager and find the sound driver HD Audio, double click it and go to driver tab, there should be a Roll Back Driver button, click it to install the old driver.

[image]

If this does not work you can use System Restore in W10 to roll back to an earlier system state before the problem started, to access this go to Control Panel>System>System Protection, when it opens select System Restore button and pick a date before this problem started.

[image]